# Custom element Polymer dialog size/position based on parent page

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-dialog

I just started playing around Polymer dialog. I try to create a custom element polymer dialog and use it in a paper card. However, I faced problem because the dialog appears based on the size/position of the paper card instead of the full page.

May I know how do I style it so that the dialog size/position will be based on the main page instead of the card? Thank you.

```html
Main page, paper-card is a 100x100px card:
<paper-card>
Text
<my-custom-dialog></my-custom-dialog>
</paper-card>

My-custom-dialog:
<dom-module id="my-custom-dialog">


    <style is="custom-style">

        paper-dialog {
            position: absolute;
            top: 3%;
            left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .fa-times {
            cursor: pointer
        }
    </style>


    <template>

        <i class="fa fa-object-group" aria-hidden="true" on-tap="toggleDialog"></i>

        <paper-dialog id="dialog" always-ontop entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
            <div class="buttons">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" dialog-confirm></i>
            </div>

            <strong>Text here</strong>
            
            
        </paper-dialog>

    </template>

</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-custom-dialog",
        toggleDialog: function () {
            this.$.dialog.toggle();
        },

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `paper-card { position: static; }`?

Comment: Just tried... didn't change anything

Comment: Maybe `paper-card { position: static !important; }`.

Comment: Doesn't work. My custom-paper-dialog is nested within the paper-card. I want the custom-paper-dialog to appear in size/position based on the entire page rather than the paper-card.

Comment: I know, but position of your custom element depends on position property of its parents (paper-card in this case).

Comment: You could move it outside of the `paper-card` element right? You should try to always have just the parts needed for the element itself, inside of the element.

Comment: I'm trying to make a custom popup with a question mark button within the paper-card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BartKoppelmans is correct. The paper-dialog needs to be outside the paper-card. You can still keep the button inside the card.

```
  <template>
  <paper-card style="width: 50%;">
    <i class="fa fa-object-group" aria-hidden="true" on-tap="toggleDialog">?</i>
  </paper-card>
  <paper-dialog id="dialog" always-ontop auto-fit-on-attach entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
        <div class="buttons">
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" dialog-confirm></i>
        </div>
        <strong>Text here</strong>
  </paper-dialog>

</template>
```